# How do I log "not higher than 100°C with no more than 1 digit after the decimal point" in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, jetbrains-ide

```
patient_id (integer)
first_name (30 characters or less)
last_name (30 characters or less)
temperature (not higher than 100°C with no more than 1 digit after the decimal point)
is_discharged (indicates if a patient was discharged or not)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
 ...
 temperature DECIMAL(4,1) NOT NULL,
 CHECK (temperature < 101),
 ...
);
```

[CHECK constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) are supported in MySQL 8.0.16 and later.